# ruby sort of single quoted strings

Tags: ruby, sorting

Why does ruby sort of single quoted strings go wrong?

```
a=["'string 1'","'string 1 x'"]
# => ["'string 1'", "'string 1 x'"]
a.sort
# => ["'string 1 x'", "'string 1'"]
```

I am using ruby 2.7.4p191.

Comment: This seems to be a misunderstanding. The quotes of a _string literal_ are not part of the string. In your example, there are no single quoted strings. Your strings are both double quoted and they _contain_ single quotes. As characters, those single quotes are treated like any other character.

Comment: BTW, why do your strings contain those single quotes in the first place?

Comment: My imported data contains single quoted strings.

Comment: Can you edit the question adding what you would expect to be the result?

Comment: @JohnLeake if those single quote characters are in fact string delimiters, you might be importing the data incorrectly.

Comment: "go wrong" is not a precise enough problem description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: The imported csv file is clean and correct. The problem field is a material name and it is surrounded in single quotes.  From a users point of view the sort order is confusing, and most would expect the shorter string to be ordered first.

Comment: I mostly disagree with this. I wouldn't expect a shorter string to be ordered first: `U2` would come before `R.E.M`

Comment: Sorry I mean the shorter of two similar single quoted strings "'string 1 x' "and "'string 1'"

Answer (score 8):

The result is not wrong, it's what it should be expected. Length of the strings doesn't matter, and strings are compared lexicographically - each character is compared to the character on the same position in the other string. The space character (ASCII 32) comes before the single quote character (ASCII 39), so `'string 1 x'` is actually "less than" `'string 1'`.

Comment: Or as a very short example: `" " < "'" #=> true`